# Where is specified that there is a "onXYZ" in document?

Tags: javascript, events, dom, w3c, specifications

I know that some browsers provide supported HID events via a definied `onXYZ` property in `document`, so that one might test e.g. for touch support by testing

```
if ("ontouchstart" in document) {
    ...
}
```

[image: Chrome watch]

The question is: *which specification defines that a element should contain these `onXYZ` properties?*

This question is **not** about: *can I use this, should I use this, which browser supports this...*

I've looked through nearly all DOM, events related specifications in

> http://www.w3.org/TR/tr-technology-stds

but didn't found a trace.

---

#### Update: Clarification:

I'm looking for a specification wording like this:

> A browser should define a attribute named `onEVENTNAME` if it does trigger `EVENTNAME` on some event.

```
 Interface MouseEvents:
     onmousedown: null; // define to tell there is a mousedown events can can be listened to
     onmouseup: null;
     ...

 DomElement implementes MouseEvents:
     ...
```

Comment: browse through the [DOM level N Events specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20131105/) - But in theory, no matter what the element, you can add an event listener for any event to it. (ie: delegation). Even so: you can also create/trigger your own, non-existent events, and add handlers for those, too

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events (the link to it from the page you posted is under Javascript APIs)

Comment: @numbers1311407: could you please cite the part where that spec says "`browsers sould provide a "on" + EVENTNAME property in the document object if event EVENTNAME is available`"? This is what I'm looking for. @Elias Van Ootegem: I browsed through them (not all appendix' actually, but the core document of course)

Comment: Are you looking for the touch events explicitly, or a generic statement?

Comment: @Bergi since these properties are defined for all kind of events, not only mouse or touch events, I assume there must be either a generic statement (_this is what I'm looking for_) or all browser vendors do the same un-specified thing. ;)

Comment: Yes, there is (see @Alohci's answer), though the touch-events spec seems to have forgotten to define these particular attributes :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property on the object whose name starts with "on" followed by the event type name is called the "Event Handler IDL Attribute". Note that an Event Handler is not the same thing as an Event Listener.

[Section 7.1.5.2.1 of HTML5.1](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/webappapis.html#idl-definitions) lists the Event Handler IDL Attributes and the objects to which they apply.

Note that this doesn't include the Touch interface. There's two points to take from that.

1. There's no requirement for there to be `ontouchstart`, `ontouchend`, etc event handlers, either in HTML5 or in the Touch Events spec, and indeed they are not necessary to use touch events, since listeners can be matched with the event types using `addEventListener`.
2. There's nothing that precludes a new or updated spec from adding a requirement for event handlers for such events, nor from browsers implementing such handlers in advance of them being documented in a spec.

As a consequence, `if ("ontouchstart" in document)` is not a good test. Maybe a better way of testing for touch support would be creating a TouchEvent and checking its type.

---

Incidentally, contrast [the Touch events spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/), which doesn't mention event handlers, with the more hardware agnostic Pointer events spec which does provide [a list of event handlers for pointer events](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-pointerevents-20130509/#extensions-to-the-globaleventhandlers-interface)